# how to generate a token or bearrer token in logic apps oauth2? I have client id, client secret, client name and password

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am new to logic apps. I want to create a bearer token in logic apps. I have client id, client secret, client username, password and endpoint. After generating the key i want to make use of that token and post the data in logic apps.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token) to get access token with your `clientId` and `clientSecret`.

[image]

Then use `Parse Json` to decode your response body to json with schema as below:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "access_token": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "expires_in": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "ext_expires_in": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "token_type": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

The end is [sending the access token as header](https://medium.com/@gamacy/how-to-pass-a-bearer-token-using-azure-logic-apps-b90d597ddce7) to website which is authenticated. The snap as below:

[image]

Comment: Is any custom operation/block is available, where we could just login while creating a logic app and at runtime the token will be fetched from OAuth & passed to next operation.

Comment: This answer should be accepted. Worked perfectly for me!